# Discord.py - Message becomes a 'None Type' object in a loop

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to create a help command with a dict and some message editing for each items of the dict with a loop, but when I use the help command it returns the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'edit'` when **it comes to the ping command** and I don't understand why `help_msg` becomes a 'NoneType' object...
Here's the code:

````
@bot.command(aliases = ['h','aide'])
async def help(ctx):
    help_msg = await ctx.send("__**Available commands:**__")
    for commande, info in help_list.items():
        help_msg = await help_msg.edit(content=str(help_msg.content)+commande+info)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx, message=None):
    await ctx.send(f":ping_pong: Pong!  `{round(bot.latency*1000)}ms`")


p = bot.command_prefix
help_list = {
    f"``` {p}help | Alias: {', '.join(help.aliases)}```" : "Affiche la liste des commandes | ?help <commande>",
    f"``` {p}ping | Alias: {', '.join(ping.aliases)}```" : "Affiche le ping du bot en ms | ?ping"
    }
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`message.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=#discord.Message.edit) has no return value, so `help_msg` is set to none.

I believe it should work if you just remove the assignment.

```
for commande, info in help_list.items():
    await help_msg.edit(content=str(help_msg.content)+commande+info)
```